# How to sort table columns using button in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm building a website in django and I want to add button and drop down menu above the table. In drop down menu, there will be name of the columns and if i select one column and then click the button sort then table will be sort on basis of that columns.

```
def index(request):
    slist = Stock.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(slist, 20)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    slist = paginator.get_page(page)
    template = loader.get_template('stocks/screener.html')
    context = {
        'slist': slist,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

What should i do??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "order_by" function:

```py
def index(request):
    sort_column = request.GET.get('sort_by', 'default_column_name')
    slist = Stock.objects.all().order_by(sort_column)
    <other codes>
```

Comment: It will not solve my problem. I want to do it using button

Comment: when the button is clicked change the page to: 
http://<yourdomain>/<path>/?sort_by=<columnname>
replace <columnname> with the name of column you want to sort your data with.

of course this is not the best way to do it. (the better way would be to provide a REST api for the frontend to dynamically load the data)